# How to get the specific item value from array element from an external url in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get the value of address from an API output 
I send the request to that URL by :

```
echo $api=" <object data='https://apibtc.com/api/create_address?token=24373243hhhis8aa2f215437b01&callback=https://test.co'></object>";
```

OutPut is showing as:

```
{"success":true,"Res":{"Sign":"202e480b32fd6b1ea311381f3cc3a480","Adress":"1FJQUXxovyizVvMhjjUMuY1QkScZbS5ipp","Address":"1FJQUXxovyizVvMhjjUMuY1QkScZbS5ipp","DateEnd":"2017-10-07 12:26:25"}}
```

I want to get address value,how can i get?

I try by below method but no response.

```
echo "address:".$api->success->Sign->Address;
```

Comment: Instead `success` use `Res`, as `$api->Res->Address;` and `$api->Res->Sign;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo JSON in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597941/how-to-echo-json-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

As it is json data you have to decode it in json then you can get data

```
$json ='{"success":true,"Res":{"Sign":"202e480b32fd6b1ea311381f3cc3a480","Adress":"1FJQUXxovyizVvMhjjUMuY1QkScZbS5ipp","Address":"1FJQUXxovyizVvMhjjUMuY1QkScZbS5ipp","DateEnd":"2017-10-07 12:26:25"}}';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->Res->Adress;
```